# Buffering with dissolve type: ALL for a big feature class doesnot create a single multipart feature

Tags: arcpy, buffer, dissolve, multipart

I am using buffer tool on large complicated network (260,000 features) line shapefile to create an area shapefile. This area shapefile somehow has to be dissolved to a single multipart shapefile.

Code used:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(featureLayer , temp2, "0.5 Feet", "FULL", "FLAT", "ALL") 
arcpy.Dissolve_management(temp2, temp3, "", "", "", "")
arcpy.MultipartToSinglepart_management(temp3, outputLayer)
```

Problem:
The dissolve after buffer for some reason does not create a single multipart feature. It creates many multipart features that can't be dissolved with each other. I tried to dissolve it five consecutive times, it produced the same result.

Is there any way to dissolve all these features to create a single multipart feature?

Comment: Do the undissolved parts overlap?

Comment: Yes for most part, if they were not overlapping, they were at least touching each other.

Comment: Try`arcpy.Buffer_analysis(featureLayer , temp2, "0.5 Feet", "FULL", "FLAT", "NONE")` (different dissolve type for the buffer). Worth a shot.

Comment: setting to "NONE" doesn't work either. Infact creates the same results.

Comment: If you want a single multipart polygon from Dissolve, shouldn't the 5th parameter be "MULTI_PART"?

Comment: "MULTI_PART" s are default in Buffer_analysis() @klewis

Comment: have you checked to make sure the geometries of the input features are valid?

Comment: I had similar issue, with dataset split by straight lines. Ended up merging them in editing mode. Some sets are simply too big...

Comment: @FelixIP Exactly, they are split by straight lines. I don't want to manually combine them, as I may have to do this many times.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into a geometry limitation of the shapefile format [(Geoprocessing considerations for shapefile output)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm).

You could try running the Buffer analysis to an in_memory feature class then 
[CopyFeatures](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) to a shapefile on disk.

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(featureLayer , r"in_memory\temp2", "0.5 Feet", "FULL", "FLAT", "ALL")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(r"in_memory\temp2", "Final_Output.shp")
```

If you hit the geometry limitation again you'll probably have to use a [Dice](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dice.htm) to subset the polygons in some way or a [Generalize](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/generalize.htm).

Comment: Tried this, didn't work, same results. I have not tried Dice.

Comment: The last line of your original code block is going to break the multipart features into single parts...is that intentional?  Why create a single multipart feature only to break it up again?  This seems to be contrary to your requirement of "This area shape file somehow has to be dissolved to a single multipart shapefile."

Comment: Yes, when I use that command, all the touching features are grouped together. That's my main objective. If you got a way to group all the touching features, that would work too.

Comment: While, the issue i have addressed in the question is due to the size of the dataset. I have tried with smaller data and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Create an new feature class with the same spatial reference as the polygons you are trying to dissolve. Then use a search cursor to pull geometry objects. For each row in your buffer feature class, perform a union to create a single feature.

```
import os

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(featureLayer , temp2, "0.5 Feet", "FULL", "FLAT", "ALL") 
#get path and file name of temp3
temp3path, temp3name = os.path.split (temp3)
#create new feature class
arcpy.CreateFeatureClass_management (temp3path, temp3name, "POLYGON",
                                     spatial_reference = temp2)
#iterate buffer attributes, pull geometries
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (temp2, "SHAPE@") as curs:
    for geom, in curs:
        try:
            #union current geom with all prior geoms
            unionGeom = geom.union (unionGeom)
        except NameError:
            #first geometry, just assign it as union geometry variable
            unionGeom = geom

#insert dissolved geometry into created feature class
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (temp3, "SHAPE@") as curs:
    row = (lastGeom,)
    curs.insertRow (row)
```

...or without a new feature class, just dissolving a feature class with multiple features into a single feature:

```
#iterate buffers, get geometries
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (temp2, "SHAPE@") as curs:
    for geom, in curs:
        try:
            #union current geom with all prior geoms
            unionGeom = geom.union (unionGeom)
        except NameError:
            #first geometry, just assign it as union geometry variable
            unionGeom = geom
        #delete row
        curs.deleteRow ()

#create insert cursor
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (temp2, "SHAPE@") as curs:
    #insert final union geometry
    curs.insertRow ((unionGeom,))
```

Comment: I tested this method myself and it sadly produced a `MemoryError`.